# Установка JAVA EE

Tags: java, sdk

Подскажите чтобы поставить  jAVA EE надо иметь уже SDK JAVA SE?

Answer (score 0):

Поставить Java EE невозможно, так как это набор стандартов, а не какое-то ПО. Да и "SDK JAVA SE" не существует.

Answer (score 0):

что бы запустить веб приложение на основе java ee необходимо наличие jre или jdk. Если они не установлены, то естественно их нужно скачать и установить так как веб-приложение работать без данного ПО не будет. В jre или jdk уже включено необходимое ПО для работы с javaEE и javaSE.

**jre** необходим для запуска приложений

**jdk** необходим для разработки приложений в IDE

Comment: Приложения можно разрабатывать и без IDE.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev согласен с вами. суть конечно не конкретно в этом была.